# NullPointerException in Java bubblesort with acm dialog

Tags: java, sorting

the program gives following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myclasses.BubbleSort.run(BubbleSort.java:42)
    at acm.program.Program.runHook(Program.java:1519)
    at acm.program.Program.startRun(Program.java:1508)
    at acm.program.Program.start(Program.java:729)
    at myclasses.BubbleSort.main(BubbleSort.java:49)

what is wrong?

thank you very much!

```
package myclasses;

import acm.program.DialogProgram;

public class BubbleSort extends DialogProgram {
    int[] array;

    public int[] getArray() {
    return array;
    }

    public void setArray(int[] array) {
    this.array = array;
}   


void swap(int firstPos, int secondPos) {
    int temp = array[firstPos];
    array[firstPos] = array[secondPos];
    array[secondPos] = temp;
}

public void bubblesort() {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        j = i;
        k = array[i];
        while (j > 0 && array[j - 1] > k) {
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            --j;
        }
        array[j] = k;
    }
} 


public void run() {
    BubbleSort a = new BubbleSort();
    a.setArray(new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2});
    a.bubblesort();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(a.array.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < getArray().length; i++) sb.append(getArray()[i]).append(" ");
    println(sb);

}    


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BubbleSort().start(args);

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the for loop in your run method to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.getArray().length; i++) sb.append(a.getArray()[i]).append(" ");
```

**Explanation:**

On this line you had 2 calls to `getArray()` which will call `getArray()` on the instance of `BubbleSort` created in `main` whereas the array has been set on `a`, the instance of `BubbleSort` created in `run()` so the 2 calls to `getArray` in the for loop need to be `a.getArray()`. The array in the instance created in `main` has never been set so `getArray().length` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Check what getArray() is returning. My guess would be `null`

Or

For one of the iterations `getArray()[i]` returns `null`

Comment: I dont know why it should be return null.

Answer (score 0):

Line 42 is for (int i = 0; i < getArray().length; i++) sb.append(getArray()[i]).append(" ");

Only object that can ben null on this line getArray. So add  this to your for loop  (int i = 0; getArray()!=null && i < getArray().length; i++) .

Also I would check the method populating the content of getArray() to see why it's null.